# Decimal point showing error in Lua

Tags: lua, floating-point

I'm using ESPlorer for programming ESP8266.

```
a = 7.5
print(a)
```

This lua code shows error "malformed number near '7.5'
". Do I need to add any library or file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hex constant = malformed number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310293/hex-constant-malformed-number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which exact firmware (file) did you flash to the ESP?

I expect you might have used the 'INTEGER' version, which doesn't support floating point arithmetics, use the 'float' firmware version instead.